# Google home page Discovery Devices

Tags: actions-on-google

I finished OAuth authorization test in Google home page, I want to know how to call or find my device is then displayed in the google home page? My webhook is deployed in HEROKU.

[This is my OAuth authorization test interface, after the authorization page does not jump to the device list.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sG4KR.jpg)

[What I need is OAuth authorization after the emergence of such equipment list interface, which is someone else's product list. So, I do not know how to find the device? I hope to help.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7v4l.png)

Comment: I'm confused about what you are asking or what you're trying to do. It sounds like you're saying you've implemented an OAuth server that meets the requirements outlined at https://developers.google.com/actions/develop/identity/oauth2-code-flow, but you're then having problems getting your Action to use this?

Comment: I want to acquire some information in my account after I finished OAuth authorization, like bound device(this is ON/OFF device), I want to contorl the device by GoogleHome and hope it can be showed in Home control. The page will be gone after I finished OAuth authorization while I am testing GoogleHome, there is no device list, I don't know how to acquire my device.